# Does AdvertisingIdClient.Info.getId() returns a static Id among repeated installations of the same app?

Tags: android, google-advertising-id

It's not clear if

```
AdvertisingIdClient.Info.getId()
```

returns the same Id even if I uninstall and reinstall de app in my device.

Anyone can confirm if it's static or if it changes? And when it changes?

[Official Documentation here.](http://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient.Info.html#getId())

Answer (score 2):

Advertising Id is static and it doesn't change on instlling/uninstalling the app

Advertising Id can only be changed if user resets it.

you can reset or change your advertising id by following these steps,

**1. Go to Phone settings
2. select "Google"
3. select "Ads"**

**Then you will see the option of resetting your advertising Id**

also you can turn on/off your advertising Id

Hope this helps